# Yii2 rest api getBodyParams() can't get params load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams(), ''); from react native post

Tags: php, api, rest, react-native, yii

How can I get  param from Post  react native?
Post react native
I try here to send some data to the request yii:

```
    let  body =  {
                demande_title:demande_title,
                created_Date:created_Date,
                updated_Date:updated_Date,
                demande_Type:demande_Type,
                demande_Action:demande_Action,
                demande_status:demande_status,
                demande_content:demande_content,
                demande_color:demande_color,
                utf_utilisateur_front_id:1

            };
            let response = await fetch(url, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${getState().auth.token}`,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(body),
            });
if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("Something went wrong !");
            }
```

I want to get data with yii load param and insert(create new demand) in data base .
Code Yii :

```
 public function actionDemandeCreate()
{
    $demande = new Demande(); 
    $demande->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams(), '');
    if ($demande->save()) {
        Yii::$app->response->statusCode = 201;
        return [
            'demande_id'=>$demande->id,
            'demande_title'=>$demande->demande_title,
            'created_Date'=>$demande->created_Date,
            'updated_Date'=>$demande->updated_Date,
            'demande_Type'=>$demande->demande_Type,
            'demande_color'=>$demande->demande_color,
            'demande_Action'=>$demande->demande_Action,
            'demande_status'=>$demande->demande_status,
            'demande_content'=> $demande->demande_content,
        ];
    } else {
        Yii::error($demande->getErrors(), __METHOD__);
        throw new ServerErrorHttpException('Une erreur s\'est produite lors de la création. Merci de réessayer.');         
}
}
```

i have error with response: 
 Error : Something went wrong

Comment: `load()` function expects to get an array like Demande[demande_id] in your case `body` is wrong

Comment: What is the solution to this problem ??

Comment: you may tray  something like `let  body =  { "Demande[demande_title]": demande_title, ...}` and in your controller `$demande->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->post());`

Comment: i tried with this solution but the same error

Answer (score 0):

Solved :

```
    let  body =  {
            "demande_title":demande_title,
            "created_Date":created_Date,
            "updated_Date":updated_Date,
            "demande_Type":demande_Type,
            "demande_Action":demande_Action,
            "demande_status":demande_status,
            "demande_content":demande_content,
            "demande_color":demande_color,
            "utf_utilisateur_front_id":1,     };
        let response = await fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${getState().auth.token}`,
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(body),});
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Something went wrong !");}
```

Yii  :

```
 $demande = new Demande();

    $params = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams();
    Yii::trace(print_r($params, true), __METHOD__);
    $demande->load($params, '');

   if ($demande->save()) {
        Yii::$app->response->statusCode = 201;
        return 
        [
    'demande_id'=>$demande->demande_id,
    'demande_title'=>$demande->demande_title,
    'created_Date'=>$demande->created_Date,
    'updated_Date'=>$demande->updated_Date,
    'demande_Type'=>$demande->demande_Type,
    'demande_color'=>$demande->demande_color,
    'demande_Action'=>$demande->demande_Action,
    'demande_status'=>$demande->demande_status,
    'demande_content'=> $demande->demande_content,
];
    } else {
        Yii::error($demande->getErrors(), __METHOD__);
        throw new ServerErrorHttpException('Une erreur s\'est produite lors de la création. Merci de réessayer.');         
}
```